# How to iterate through a python dictionary from user input?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, input

**Background:**

I have a `JSON dictionary` file as follows:

```
dictionary = {"Qui": "クイ", "Quiana": "キアナ", "Quick": "クイック", "Quickley": "クイックリー", "Quico": "キコ", "Quiej-Alvarez": "クエイ アルバレス", "Quigg": "クイッグ", "Quigley": "クイグリー", "Quijano": "クイジャーノ", "Quik": "クイック", "Quilici": "クイリチ", "Quill": "クィル"}
```

Then I will let the user enter as many keys as they want through input, finally  return formatted string combined with `key.value`.

**Question:**

My code so far gets the job done in a very clunky/incomplete manner. Any advice on how to clean up the code and achieve my goal?

**Current code:**

```
import json
import sys, math
import codecs

#Part1
search_term,search_term2 = input("Enter a Name: ").split()
dictionary = {}
keys = dictionary.keys()
values = dictionary.values()
with open ('translation.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    term_data = json.load(f)
if search_term.casefold() in term_data:
    word = search_term.title()     
elif search_term.title() in term_data:
    word = search_term.title()     
output1 = "{}".format(term_data[search_term])
#Part 2
with open ('translation.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    term_data2 = json.load(f)
if search_term2.casefold() in term_data2:
    word2 = search_term2.title()    
elif search_term2.title() in term_data2:
    word2 = search_term2.title()     
#else:
    #print("Name not found in dictionary.")
output2 = "{}".format(term_data2[search_term2])
print("{}・{}".format(output1,output2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code can just enter 2 keys which cannot meet your original requirements, I expand as follows, meanwhile make it simpler:

**test.py**:

```
import json
import codecs

with open('translation.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    term_data = json.load(f)

search_terms = input("Enter a name: ").split()
l = [term_data[i] for i in search_terms if i.casefold() in term_data or i.title() in term_data]
print('.'.join(l))
```

- First we just need to open json file once, it's expensive to do `IO` operation, we need to avoid to do it again and again.
- Second, we needn't repeat term match as you do with `Part1`, `Part2`. We can do it in loop, here I use `list comprehension`.
- Finally, explain a litte:

  - split all user inputs to a list: `search_terms`
  - loop a user input terms with `for i in search_terms`
  - if the candidate term `i`'s `casefold()` or `title()` in dictionary `term_data`, it's value in dic was put to new list `l` again, if not do nothing.
  - at last, use the separator `.` to join all the needed elements of list.

**Output:**

```
~$ python3 test.py
Enter a name: Qui Quill Quiana
クイ.クィル.キアナ
```